# How do I input a word without having to click the input field in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Basically, the user enters a scene where he has to enter some sort of password of 4 letters to win. I plan to use no cursor in the game so I don't want to use the input field where you have to click it, then type the word, but if necessary I can do that. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Unity's Input Field Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.ActivateInputField.html), use the `ActivateField()` method

> Description
>
> Function to activate the InputField to begin processing Events.
>
> Will only activate if deactivated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField mainInputField;

    // Activate the main input field when the Scene starts.
    void Start()
    {
        mainInputField.ActivateInputField();
    }
}
```